# Why is .length giving me the length of the return statement as opposed to user input?

Tags: java

First question here, I've searched around quite a bit for applying the .length method to user input. Unfortunately none of the questions that have been answered touch on the specifics of my situation.

I'm working a school project that has two parts. The first part is rolling 2 dice until the sum of the 2 dice are either 7 or 11, then printing a message saying what each die rolled, and their total.

The second part of the assignment is where I am having trouble. We are supposed to get the user to input 2 strings and have Java order the 2 strings alphabetically, and use .length to display the length of the two strings, then add them up. I've gotten as far as getting user input, but when I try to calculate the length of the strings, it just gives me the length of the return string at the end of the method.  So when the user inputs "Hello" and "Goodbye" I end up getting 10 and 26, because it's counting the length of "Thank you!" and "Thank you! Now watch this!" I've tried putting the .length within the 'inputString' and 'inputAnotherString' method, which didn't work.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        boolean keepRolling = true;
        while (keepRolling) {
            int dieOne = rollDice();
            int dieTwo = rollDice();
            int diceTotal = (dieOne + dieTwo);

            if (diceTotal == 7 || diceTotal == 11) {
                System.out.println("You rolled a " + dieOne + " and a " + dieTwo + ": total = " + diceTotal + ". You win!");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("You rolled a " + dieOne + " and a " + dieTwo + ": total = " + diceTotal + ". Roll again!");
            }
        }

        String firstString;
        firstString = inputString();
        System.out.println(firstString);

        String secondString;
        secondString = inputAnotherString();
        System.out.println(secondString);

        int lengthOne = firstString.length();
        System.out.println(lengthOne);

        int lengthTwo = secondString.length();
        System.out.println(lengthTwo);

        int totalLength = lengthOne + lengthTwo;
        System.out.println(totalLength);

    }

    public static int rollDice() {

        return 1+ (int)(Math.random()*((6-1)+1));

    }

    public static String inputString() {

        String stringOne;
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter a string!");
        try {
            stringOne = in.readLine();
        } catch(IOException e) {

        }
        return "Thank you!";
    }

    public static String inputAnotherString() {

        String stringTwo;
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter another string!");
        try {
            stringTwo = in.readLine();
        } catch(IOException e) {

        }
        return "Thank you! Now watch this!";
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Because what you return, is what you *return* and what gets resolved to `firstString`, and then when you take the `length()` of `firstString`, you get the length of what you returned. You want to return `stringOne` and not `"thank you"`

Comment: `inputString()` returns `"Thank you!"`, not the value entered by the user, which is in local variable `stringOne`. `firstString = inputString()` then means that `firstString = "Thank you!"`, and `lengthOne = firstString.length()` means that `lengthOne = 10`. Why is this confusing you?

Comment: *FYI:* Do not create multiple `BufferedReader` on `System.in`.

Comment: Also do not eat exceptions. You will want to print the message in your catch blocks. And I would highly recommend learning to use the debugger, as it will help you solve problems like this very easily

Comment: @GBlodgett I actually don't even know what the try/catch section of this code does. I never got an explanation from my teacher on how to get user input in code where there's multiple methods (cause the 'throws IOException' doesn't apply to the other methods), and so I found this piece of code from a previous example, which had no explanation attached to it. Basically, using it was the only way I could get the user input part to work. I know what I just said barely makes any sense, but I'm really new to all of this. Thanks for the advice though!

Comment: The try catch statement does the following: It executes the code between the try-brackets. If an exception occurs, it looks whether that exception will get caught or not (IOException for example). If it gets caught, everything between the catch-statement gets executed. I think for what you are currently trying to do, you don't need a try catch statement there. I would recommend to just delete it for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign the variables to the functions you are calling, meaning that they get assigned to the return value of those functions. Because of this, firstString gets the return value of inputString() (in this case "Thank you!"). You have to return the inputted string in your functions like so:

```
public static String inputString() {

    String stringOne;
    BufferedReader in;
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter a string!");
    try {
        stringOne = in.readLine();
    } catch(IOException e) {

    }
    return stringOne;
}
```

Though you might want to see how you handle exceptions in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I should've mentioned also that I tried returning stringOne, but IntelliJ says 'variable might not have been initialized and obviously doesn't run after. It was after that didn't worked that I tried to just return a what I have in the example above.

Comment: You're welcome. You get this message because you only declare stringOne when you don't have to catch an IOExcepiton, that is why I told you to look into that. You will see how there is no warning or error when you remove the try catch statements. Maybe just say that in case of an error, let stringOne just be "". In this case, stringOne will have been initialized when reaching the return statement and there will be no error or warning.

Comment: That just solved everything. Thank you so much! Great first experience with stackoverflow. Is there a rep/upvote system or anything here that I could give you?

Comment: You are welcome! I'm happy to have provided you with that experience. Usually, the person who asked the question accepts the answer if it has solved his problem and upvotes it. In your case you can only accept the answer as you don't have enough reputation yet. You can accept an answer by clicking the check mark beneath the two rectangles and number to the left of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

your method `public static String inputString()` returns "Thank you!" instead of what the user has input. In that case, by setting a variable calling `firstString = inputString();` it sets firstString to be "Thank you!". Thus calling `firstString.length();` returns you the length of "Thank you!" instead of the input that users give.